# Linux host wordpress file upload size limit still 2MB despite all solutions online

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, wordpress

I'm struggling to increase file upload size on my linux machine where I host my wordpress website...
Things I tried and that are still active:
.htaccess

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

wp-config.php

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
```

editing wordpress theme functions.php

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

adding php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
```

and doing service apache2 restart so it's not the restart...
These are all the fixes I could find online and I became pretty desperate being stuck on this problem for so long ... Hopefully someone will help!

Answer (score 0):

I somehow managed to overcome this error... The solution was to edit the php.ini located at

```
/etc/php/7.3/apache2
```

if even that doesn't work for you, try editing php.ini at these locations as well:

```
/etc/php/7.3/cli

/etc/php/7.3/cgi
```

adding this line

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
```

and maybe this too

```
post_max_size 64M
```

conclusion.. if you have your own linux server you will have to change the apache2 default php.ini settings because even if you setup the new php.ini at wordpress files location, the one in apache2 folder is apsolute so firstly you need to increase upload_max_filesize there.